# Python equivalent to templates in ansible

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, ansible

Is there any way to achieve ansible template equivalent in python? I basically have a json payload (dictionary in python) which I want to use in the code and I would like to have the payload as a json file and would like to import the file and replace the variables inside the json after I import (Ansible template)

payload.json

```json
{
"var1": "%var1%",
"var2": "%var2%"
}
```

main.py

```
import json
# some stuff
with open('payload.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
data['var1']=var1
data['var2']=var2
# use data as needed
```

what I am looking for

```
import json
# some stuff
with open('payload.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
do_some_magic(data) # this should set all the %var% with the actual var 
# use data as needed
```

Comment: [Ansible uses Jinja2 templating](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_templating.html), so the [jinja python API](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/api/#basics) should work for you. (Note: to get **all** workspace variables use `**globals()`.